# Source code for Arduino “firmware”?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am wondering if anyone here knows where the source code for the Arduino "firmware" is available for reading? I think it must be more than the 'boot loader' but I am not sure. Thanks!

p.s. I assume this kind of question is ok here, even though it's not ok on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 7):

The “firmware” is whatever program a microcontroller runs. On an
Arduino, it is typically the program **you** write and upload into the
microcontroller's flash memory.

If by “firmware” you mean the core library (the source code of
`pinMode()`, `digitalRead()` and so on), it is here:

https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr

If by “firmware” you mean the bootloader (the small program that runs at
reset and will accept the upload of your firmware), is is here:

https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/hardware/arduino/avr/bootloaders/optiboot

Note that this is valid for the AVR-based Arduinos.
The cores and bootloaders used in other architectures are stored is
separate repositories, e.g.

https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-sam

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for the Flash Firmware, I think the github project documentation is pretty well developed, here:

https://github.com/arduino/Arduino

This is a good introduction to build and flash your Arduino UNO:

http://angryelectron.com/arduino-firmware/

And here a good start to build you own Arduino on a breadboard:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/standalone

Comment: Thanks. The arduino/arduino github repo looks like java so I think it's for their IDE. Thanks for the other links, I will followup.

Comment: @pitosalas: that GitHub repo also has the source of the AVR core and a few extra libraries.